# File and Image Upload in a Wygwam field in a Safecracker Form

Tags: safecracker, wygwam, pixelandtonic, file-uploads, image

I was trying to find confirmation about whether the Browse Server button in the Image and File Upload functionality in Wygwam could be used in Safecracker. Currently the windows pop open fine, but the Browse Server button is not visible.

The only reference I could find was http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/223476/ which suggested switching to Ckfinder for the File Manager, which I tried and then wasn't able to see the Browse Server button on the frontend or the backend.

I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null that seems unrelated, because it occurs regardless of whether the Browse Server button appears or not.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have Wygwam configured to use EE’s file browser, it will fall back on CKFinder within Safecracker, since the EE file browser doesn’t work there.

The only issue is that CKFinder is only able to work with a single upload directory. So you have to go into Add-Ons > Modules > Wygwam > [your config name] and tell it which upload directory to use.